# Getting 2D array from a function into a variable in main()

Tags: c#

I am a begginer in C#. I have a problem that can be simply solved by you guys. I have a function that creates 2D array with numbers and returns it. I would like to use this function in main() to get this 2D array in main(). Here is a code that doesn't work (it prints "Y:" only). Could you please help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Simulation
    {

        static int[,] Initialize(int x, int a, int b)
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            int[,] positions = new int[2,x];
            for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
                positions[0,i]=a*r.Next();
                positions[1,i]=b*r.Next();
            }
            return positions;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] array=Initialize(100,100,100);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Y:", array[1, 1]);
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Have a good day!

Comment: Use a debugger to inspect what values are actually in your variables. As you can see here, printing text to the console is not always helping.

Comment: System.Console.WriteLine("Y:"+ array[1, 1]); // '+' between the strings, not ','

Comment: You don't need to use the `System` namespace to refer to `Console.WriteLine()` or `Console.ReadKey()`, because you already have a `using System;` directive at the top of the file.  For example, `System.Console.ReadKey();` can simply be written as `Console.ReadKey();`.

Answer (score 5):

Your line for the output should be:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Y: {0}", array[1, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A small problem at `System.Console.WriteLine("Y:", array[1, 1]);` line, either use

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Y: " + array[1, 1]);
```

or

```
 System.Console.WriteLine("Y: {0}",  array[1, 1]);
```